# jQuery text effect not rendering with individual letters

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to take an h1 that says "hello world", and using lettering.js(see below), break up h1 into a series of spans so I can change the colors of the letters individually to make a rainbow effect. I also want to use the jumble text effect found here: http://cozuya.github.io/TextEffect-jQuery-plugin/. Here is a link to the lettering plugin: https://github.com/davatron5000/Lettering.js .

Essentially what happens is, the colors will get changed, but the letters will not jumble, and the colors will revert back to white after a few moments.
I've tried using .delay() before the lettering call, putting one in a script before the other, nothing seems to get these two plug ins to work together.

This is what the h1 "hello world" will look like after .lettering is called:

```
<h1 id = "letters">
  <span class="char1">"</span>
  <span class="char2">h</span>
  <span class="char3">e</span>
  <span class="char4">l</span>
  <span class="char5">l</span>
  <span class="char6">o</span>
  <span class="char7"> </span>
  <span class="char8">w</span>
  <span class="char9">o</span>
   ... and so on
</h1>
```

**my jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#letters').textEffect({effect: 'jumble', 
    effectSpeed: 150, 
    completionSpeed: 6000 
  });   
  $("#letters").lettering();
});
```

**CSS**:

```
#letters .char10 {
  color: #94C472;
}
#letters .char11 {
  color: #B33E92;
}
#letters .char12 {
  color: #D18D61;
}
#letters .char13 {
  color: #DA3C40;
}
#letters .char14 {
  color: #1AAAA2;
}
#letters .char15 {
  color: #1AAAA2;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These plugins are not compatible as is. The reason for your behavior is:

1. `$('#letters').textEffect(...)` is delayed due to timeouts for animation
2. `$("#letters").lettering()` is executed before the `textEffect` is done rendering. The `lettering` plugin is modifying the element it is causing the issue you noticed where jumble is not working (it transformed element with text node into element with multiple `span` elements, but the `textEffect` plugin is just expecting a string of text, it does its own manipulation into `span` elements).

To get this working a couple simple modifications to the `textEffect` plugin were required. I changed the `jumble` and `runJumble` functions.

**`jumble`**

Removed the call to `self.reset()` which was why the colors changed back after the delay, like you pointed out. This was changing the individual span tags back into a regular text node. (I commented it out to show where it was; see below)

Created a `colorArray` with your example colors. This could be whatever you want, and could easily be modified to be passed with the `options`. The `colorArray` is passed to `runJumble` for the jumbled letters' color, and is also used to set the correct letter's color after the jumble animation completes.

**`runJumble`**

Used `colorArray` to set the jumbled letter's color. This replaced the option `options.jumbleColor` and so effectively changed how the function works (picks a color from the array at random instead of using a single color defined by the option).

This is just for example purposes -- you would probably want to take this a step further and create different methods, perhaps called `rainbowJumble` instead of messing with the original `jumble`, or you could add an option `{rainbow:true}` and branch on the different color behavior. Then you could do a pull request and get it merged into the plugin in GitHub. Wiz!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#letters').textEffect({effect: 'jumble', 
    effectSpeed: 150, 
    completionSpeed: 6000 
  });   
});

// from http://cozuya.github.io/TextEffect-jQuery-plugin/javascripts/textEffect.jquery.js
// jQuery text effect plugin created by Chris Ozols copywrite MIT license 2013
// v0.1.6

if ( typeof Object.create !== 'function' ) {
 Object.create = function( obj ) {
  function F() {}
  F.prototype = obj;
  return new F();
 };
}

(function( $, window, document, undefined ) {

 var TextEffect = {
  init: function (options, elem) {
   var _options = {};
   this.$elem = $(elem);
   this.oldText = this.$elem.html();
   typeof options === 'string' ? _options.effect = options : _options = options;
   this.options = $.extend( {}, $.fn.textEffect.options, _options );
   this[this.options.effect]();
  },

  setup: function (effectOption) {
   this.textArray = [];
   this.$elem.html('');  // oddly jQuery.empty() doesn't work as well here.
   for (var i = 0; i < this.oldText.length; i++) {
    this.textArray[i] = "<span class='text-effect' style='" + effectOption + "'>" + this.oldText.substr(i, 1) + "</span>";
    this.$elem.append(this.textArray[i]);
   }
  },

  random: function () {
   var effects = ['grow', 'fade', 'jumble', 'slide', 'dropdown'];
   var effect = effects[(Math.floor(Math.random() * effects.length))];
   this[effect]();
  },

  slide: function () {
   var startPosition = (this.$elem.offset().left + this.$elem.width());
   this.setup('visibility: hidden; position: relative; left: ' + startPosition + 'px;');
   this.run('left', 0);
  },

  dropdown: function () {
   var offscreen = this.$elem.offset().top + this.$elem.height() * 1.1;  // little extra padding
   this.setup('position: relative; bottom: ' + offscreen + 'px;');
   this.run('bottom', 0);   
  },

  grow: function () {
   this.setup('font-size: 0px;');
   this.run('fontSize', this.$elem.css('fontSize'));
  },

  fade: function () {
   this.$elem[0].style.opacity !== undefined ? this.setup('opacity: 0;') : this.setup('filter: alpha(opacity=0); display: inline-block;');  // IE8 and below. jQuery handles animating opacity natively.
   this.run('opacity', this.$elem.css('opacity'));
  },

  jumble: function () {
   var self = this;
            var colorArray = ["#94C472","#B33E92","#D18D61","#DA3C40","#1AAAA2","#1AAAA2"];
   var letterArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];
   var i = 0;
   this.setup();
   var jumbleEffectInterval = setInterval(function () {
    if (self.jumbleInterval) {
     clearInterval(self.jumbleInterval);
    }
    self.runJumble(letterArray, colorArray, i);

    self.$elem.children('span.text-effect').eq(i).html(self.oldText.substr(i, 1)).css('color', colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * (colorArray.length - 1))]);
    if (i === (self.oldText.length - 1)) {
     clearInterval(jumbleEffectInterval);
     //self.reset(); // omit reset. this was changing the charcter spans back to plain text
    } else {
     i++;
    }
   }, self.options.effectSpeed);
  },

  runJumble: function (letterArray, colorArray, jumbleLength) {
   var self = this;
   this.jumbleInterval = setInterval(function () {
    for (var i = (self.textArray.length - 1); i > jumbleLength; i--) {
     if (self.oldText.substr(i, 1) !== ' ') {
      self.$elem.children('span.text-effect').eq(i).html(letterArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * (letterArray.length - 1))]).css('color', colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * (colorArray.length - 1))]);
     } else {
      self.$elem.children('span.text-effect').eq(i).html(' ');
     }
    }
   }, 70);
  },

  run: function (effect, oldEffect) {
   var self = this;
   var obj = {};
   var i;
   obj[effect] = oldEffect;
   this.options.reverse ? i = this.textArray.length - 1 : i = 0;
   var $spans = self.$elem.children('span.text-effect');
   var effectInterval = setInterval(function () {
    $spans.eq(i).css('visibility', 'visible').animate(obj, self.options.completionSpeed / self.textArray.length, function () {
      if ($(this).index() === self.textArray.length - 1 && !self.options.reverse || self.options.reverse && $(this).index() === 0) {
       clearInterval(effectInterval);
       self.reset();
      }
     });
    self.options.reverse ? i-- : i++;
   }, self.options.effectSpeed);
  },

  reset: function () {
   this.$elem.html(this.oldText);
  }
 };

 $.fn.textEffect = function(options) {
  return this.each(function() {
   var texteffect = Object.create(TextEffect);
   texteffect.init(options, this);
  });
 };

 $.fn.textEffect.options = {
  effect: 'random',
  effectSpeed: 150,
  completionSpeed: 6000,
  jumbleColor: '#7f7f7f',
  reverse: false
 };
})( jQuery, window, document );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id = "letters">goodbye cruel world</h1>
```